# Using CUDA Profiler nvprof for memory accesses

Tags: cuda, profiling, gpgpu, gpu, heterogeneous

I'm using nvprof to get the number of global memory accesses for the following CUDA code. The number of loads in the kernel is 36 (accessing d_In array) and the number of stores in the kernel is 36+36 (for accessing d_Out array and d_rows array). So, the total number of global memory loads is 36 and the number of global memory stores is 72. However, when I profile the code with nvprof CUDA profiler, it reports the following: (Basically I want to compute the Compute to Global Memory Access (CGMA) ratio)

```
      1                gld_transactions        Global Load Transactions           6           6           6
      1                gst_transactions       Global Store Transactions          11          11          11
      1            l2_read_transactions            L2 Read Transactions         133         133         133
      1           l2_write_transactions           L2 Write Transactions          24          24          24


#include <stdio.h>
#include "cuda_profiler_api.h"
__constant__ int crows;

__global__ void kernel(double *d_In, double *d_Out, int *d_rows){
        int tx=threadIdx.x;
        int bx=blockIdx.x;
        int n=bx*blockDim.x+tx;
        if(n < 36){
                d_Out[n]=d_In[n]+1;
                d_rows[n]=crows;
        }
        return;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){

     double I[36]={1,5,9,2,6,10,3,7,11,4,8,12,13,17,21,14,18,22,15,19,23,16,20,24,25,29,33,26,30,34,27,31,35,28,32,36};

     double *d_In;
     double *d_Out;
     int *d_rows;

     double Iout[36];
     int rows=5;
     int h_rows[36];

     cudaMemcpyToSymbol(crows,&rows,sizeof(int));
     cudaMalloc(&d_In,sizeof(double)*36);
     cudaMalloc(&d_Out,sizeof(double)*36);
     cudaMalloc(&d_rows,sizeof(int)*36);

     cudaMemcpy(d_In,I,sizeof(double)*36,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

     dim3 dimGrid(4,1,1);
     dim3 dimBlock(10,1,1);

     cudaProfilerStart();
     kernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_In,d_Out,d_rows);
     cudaProfilerStop();

     cudaMemcpy(Iout,d_Out,sizeof(double)*36,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
      cudaMemcpy(h_rows,d_rows,sizeof(int)*36,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


    int i;
     for(i=0;i<36;i++)
       printf("%f %d\n",Iout[i],h_rows[i]);


}
```

Can someone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's customary to ask a question, something more specific than "Can someone help me?"  Your code as shown has no floating point operations (+, *, etc.) so there is no CGMA to compute (it is zero).

Regarding the memory transactions, your code has 4 threadblocks:

```
 dim3 dimGrid(4,1,1);
```

Each threadblock may run on a separate multiprocessor.  You have 10 threads in each block.  The following line of code:

```
            d_Out[n]=d_In[n]+1;
```

will generate at least one global load transaction (`d_In`) and one global store transaction (`d_Out`) to service the threads.  The fourth block will have threads whose global indices (`n`) for the active threads will be 30-35.  When this block executes the above line of code, it will generate *two* global load and *two* global store transactions, because the threads require two cachelines to service their requests.  So this one line of code may generate 5 global load transactions and 5 global store transactions.

For similar reasons, the next line of code:

```
            d_rows[n]=crows;
```

may generate 5 additional global store transactions.  So of your profiler output:

```
  1                gld_transactions        Global Load Transactions           6           6           6
  1                gst_transactions       Global Store Transactions          11
```

I believe I have explained 5 of the 6 global load transactions, and 10 of the 11 global store transactions.  Hopefully that is enough to give you an idea of the origin of these numbers.